# How to get inside of this thin white border

Tags: crop, photoshop

Original image : http://orig10.deviantart.net/cf51/f/2013/234/c/1/_8__uscail_by_el_dark_core-d6jbjv0.png

I need to get inside of this white border selection how to do it?

Here the selection

http://orig10.deviantart.net/ef62/f/2015/174/6/4/inside_of_here_by_monstermmorpg-d8yhv3e.png

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with scripting photoshop - so it is off topic for this forum.  You may have better luck at Super User, Photography, or Graphic Design.

Answer (score 1):

With your selection tool selected, right click the selected area > Select Inverse this will select the area outside of the border. Now go to Select > Modify > Expand. Enter certain pixels according to the resolution of your image (about 10-30). Now your border is selected. Alternatively, you can experiment with the quick select tool.

Comment: ty for answer however it selects both sides of selected area if you use inverse. i updated question to be more clear